# Variable padding to justify Elements

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding, justify

I want to create justified elements inside a div. It works, but the space between the elements is different. I want that it looks like in a table. The inside divs need something like variable paddings.

I don't know and cannot calculate the width of the elements, so i cannot style it fix or put them in tables.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dvnjd6j/2/).

**TABLE**

```
<table cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>short content</td>
        <td>bit longer content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>this is a very long content</td>
        <td>short content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>short content</td>
        <td>this is a very long content</td>
        <td>short content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>this is a very long content</td>
        <td>short content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**DIV**

```
<div class="elem">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>bit longer content</div>
    <div>short content</div>
    <div>this is a very long content</div>
    <div>short content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>short content</div>
    <div>this is a very long content</div>
    <div>short content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>this is a very long content</div>
    <div>short content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}

td{
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.elem{
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}

.elem div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a table display (`display: table`)?

Comment: because when i use `table` for the container and `inside-block` for the children, i don't get the justify-effect. with `table` and `table-cell` the children are all in one line.

Comment: You can wrap the `table-cell` elements in a `table-row` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `display: flex`. There is some pretty cool stuff you can do with it.
Here's a helpful link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you. flex did it: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1dvnjd6j/6/). Nice feature. Never saw it before.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between each `div` in HTML structure when you are using `display:inline-block;`  So, it will not take variable space.

```
<div class="elem">
    <div>blabla</div><div>blablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blablablablablablablabla</div><div>blablablabla</div><div>blabla</div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/1dvnjd6j/3/)

And also you can set `padding` and `margin` as per your need.

```
.elem div{
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1dvnjd6j/5/)